# How to pass an ADODB Recordset to a function in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, parameter-passing, recordset

I'm trying to take an ADODB recordset that is an extract of Active Directory data and then do a recursive search through it to build the equivalent of an organizational tree starting at a given name. In order of preference, I would like to find out how to make one of the following work:
   1. Ideally I would like to create the recordset in one function and read it in another.
   2. Create the recordset as global, fill it in one function and read from it in another
   3. Minimally, I need to create it in the body of the script and read it in a function due to recursively building the list of names.
Any help you can give will be immensely appreciated. Here is my code:

```
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [string]$Name,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [string[]]$Attr
    )

    Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

    function Get-ADData() {
        Param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            [string[]] $Attr,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            [string] $Filter
        )

        $conAdData = new-Object  -com "ADODB.Connection"
        $comAdData = new-Object -com "ADODB.Command"
        $rsAdData = New-Object -ComObject "ADODB.Recordset"        

        $conAdData.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
        $conAdData.Open( "Active Directory Provider")
        $comAdData.ActiveConnection = $conAdData

        $comAdData.Properties.Item("Page Size").value = 1000
        $comAdData.Properties.item("Searchscope").value = 2

        $comAdData.CommandText = "Select " + ($attr -join ", ") + " From 'LDAP://jive.jive.com:3268/DC=jive,DC=jive,DC=com' Where " + $Filter
        $rsAdData = $comAdData.Execute()
        $rsAdData
    }

    function Get-Subordinates() {
        Param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            [string] $Name,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            $Recordset
         )

        $aaData = @{}
        $fields = @()

        $Recordset.MoveFirst()
        $Recordset.Find("Name = '" + $Name + "'")

        $aaData.Add($Name, "")

        if ($Recordset.Fields.Item("directReports"))
        {
            $arReports = ($Recordset.Fields.Item("directReports")) -split ';'

            ForEach ($report in $arReports)
            {
                if ($report.Trim() -ne "")
                {
                    Write-Host $report
                    $report = ($report -split ",")[0,1] -join ","
                    $report = $report.Substring(3)
                    $report = $report.Replace("\", "")
                    $aaData += Get-Subordinates -Name $report
                }
            }
        }
        $aaData
    }

    $objRecordSet = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Recordset

    # Set the name for the top of the tree
    # if it's not set
    if (!$Name)
    {
        $Name = "Turkey, Jive"
    }

    # Creat the list of attributes we want to collect
    # And add the supplied attribute if one was supplied
    # Name and directReports are necessary to build the tree
    if ($Attr)
    {
        $Attr = @("Name", $Attr, "Manager", "directReports") 
    }
    else
    {
        $Attr = @("Name", "sAMAccountName", "Manager", "directReports")
    }

    # Filter used to get AD information. Strip out non users and any account
    # without either a Manager or name
    $Filter = "objectCategory = 'Person' And Manager = '*' And name = '*'"

    # Grab our bulk AD data
    $objRecordset = Get-ADData -Attr $Attr -Filter $Filter

    # Build the tree recursively
    $aaReportData = Get-Subordinates -Name $Name -Recordset $objRecordSet
```

Comment: That's a painful way to query active directory from Powershell. Why don't you use [Active Directory Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx) instead of relying on outdated technology (Adodb)?

Comment: I found doing a forest level query in a multi-domain forest to be exceedingly painful with the AD Cmdlets. I may be doing something wrong there, but it was quite a process to build the list of domains and then query each one till I had a hit.

Comment: What is the problem/error message that you are getting? I think that all you need is to have a `Write-Output` statement at the end of your `Get-ADData` function to "Return" the object from your function. i.e. `Write-Output $rsAdData`

Comment: OK, I'm going to blame long day and distractions. I need to add .value or all I get is the data type. Thanks for looking!